# When will the links (Newsfeed, OneDrive, Site) be updated after changing AAM?

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

I have installed a new sharepoint farm. It used the default URL as the first web application name (machinename:80). In AAM I changed machinename:80 to www.domain.com in default zone.

May I know when will the links be updated? Do I need to do it manually or the search components will update for me? Thanks.